# `loading` route in NextJs 13 now working properly while using parallel intercepted routes?

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing, react-server-components

I am creating an app to learn about the new Nextjs features. My app directory is structured like this-

```
-@modal
  -(.)blog
    -[title]
      -page.tsx
      -layout.tsx
      -loading.tsx
-blog
  -[title]
    -page.tsx
    -loading.tsx
-layout.tsx
-page.tsx
-loading.tsx
```

This structure intercepts the `/blog/:title` route while accessing from root `/`.

Now, the route interception is working fine but there is no loading state. i.e. the file `@modal/(.)blog/[title]/loading.tsx` is not being utilized.
There is not much about this in their [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/intercepting-routes). Has someone done this or Is there any other way to add loading states in intercepted parallel routes?

(P.S.- Somehow I need to manually delete the `.next` folder everytime I update a layout file or loading file in any directory. I suspect this has something to do with the new caching scheme.)

Comment: I have the same problem. I was looking for answer for this a whole day